# How to display multiplication result with 2 decimal places

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am building a query which needs to output a multiplication result of two fields as a currency value. 0.00 - 9999.99.

I have attempted several suggested solutions and so far either they give syntax errors or will round to a whole number with no decimal

Do I need separate the multiplication from the formatted result?

My current query.

```
mysql> SELECT b.RowNumber,b.Email, z.PriceMultiplier * p.Price
    -> FROM Production p JOIN Performace pe ON p.Title = pe.Title
    -> JOIN Booking b ON b.PerfDate = pe.PerfDate AND b.Perftime = pe.PerfTime
    -> JOIN Seat s ON s.RowNumber = b.RowNumber
    -> JOIN Zone z ON z.Name = s.Zone;
+-----------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
| RowNumber | Email                | z.PriceMultiplier * p.Price |
+-----------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
| Z16       | Jane.Dot@live.com    |                          60 |
| Z18       | ZP@email.com         |                          60 |
| Z19       | ZP@email.com         |                          60 |
| U19       | Jane.Dot@live.com    |          26.999999284744263 |
| U20       | Jane.Dot@live.com    |          26.999999284744263 |
| X13       | Mike.Stand@email.com |          26.999999284744263 |
| X14       | Mike.Stand@email.com |          26.999999284744263 |
| Z19       | qvf3@live.com        |                          60 |
+-----------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Datatypes - PriceMultiplier FLOAT NOT NULL and Price DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL

The TRUNCATE command appears to be most recommended however it is rounding

26.999999284744263 - should become 26.99 , not 27

Comment: What is the datatype of PriceMultiplier and Price?

Comment: PriceMultiplier FLOAT NOT NULL and Price DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After settings both data types to Float.

PriceMultiplier FLOAT NOT NULL and Price FLOAT NOT NULL

Truncate worked, without rounding.

U19       | Jane.Dot@live.com    |                                               26.99 |

Comment: when you get an answer that solves your problem consider accepting it. Read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Answer (score 1):

You need the function [`TRUNCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate):

```
TRUNCATE(p.BasicTicketPrice * z.PriceMultiplier, 2)
```

For example:

```
select truncate(26.999999284744263, 2)
```

returns

```
26.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's Round function in your query - ROUND(number, decimals)

e.g. SELECT ProductName, Price, ROUND(Price, 1) AS RoundedPrice
FROM Products;  - Taken from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_round.asp

For your particular query, try something like

```
SELECT b.RowNumber, b.Email, ROUND(p.BasicTicketPrice * z.PriceMultiplier,2) AS Price FROM Booking b 
JOIN Performance pe ON pe.PerfDate = b.PerfDate AND b.PerfTime = pe.PerfTime 
JOIN Production p ON pe.Title = p.Title JOIN Seat s ON b.RowNumber = s.RowNumber 
JOIN Zone z ON s.Zone = z.Name WHERE s.Zone = z.Name;
```

Truncate also gives the answer you are after

```
SELECT Truncate(26.999999284744263, 2);

26.99
```

Good luck with your studies

Comment: 26.999999284744263 - should become 26.99 , not 27. Round gives me 27

Comment: SELECT b.RowNumber, b.Email, ROUND(p.BasicTicketPrice * z.PriceMultiplier,2) AS Price FROM Booking b 
JOIN Performance pe ON pe.PerfDate = b.PerfDate AND b.PerfTime = pe.PerfTime 
JOIN Production p ON pe.Title = p.Title JOIN Seat s ON b.RowNumber = s.RowNumber 
JOIN Zone z ON s.Zone = z.Name WHERE s.Zone = z.Name;

Comment: @Gooze no, 26.999999284744263 should be rounded to 27. Did you mean "truncate" to 2 decimals?